# Issue's with getting Cisco ASA to be ingested to the CommonSecurityLog data table

Tags: syslog, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

thank you for your time and help on this. I am having relentless issue's with getting Cisco ASA ingested to the CommonSecurityLog data table. I think it's stems from how I'm receiving the messages via syslog and my understanding of the architecture of the omsagent and how it differentiates between CEF and Syslog. Currently, we don't have anything writing to any syslog facilities. I am writing my cisco asa messages to a custom file that is generated everyday. It it sending on TCP/1470 because cisco asa does not support TCP/514. The logs are flowing to the machine successfully, so I don't have a conf syntax issue. Although I can't seem to find anything helpful to get this in to Sentinel now that it is sitting on my syslog server outside of creating a custom log that won't have field mapping. Below is what my syslog-ng.conf looks like for the related source. I also ran the validate connectivity script within the data connector page to make sure everything was okay with the agent connecting to the workspace.

```
source s_cisco {
        tcp(port(1470));
};

destination d_cisco_asa { file("/opt/syslog-ng/cisco_asa/$HOST/$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY-$SOURCEIP-cisco_asa.log");};

filter f_cisco_asa {
                                               host(x.x.x.x);
                                                };

log { source(s_cisco); filter(f_cisco_asa); destination(d_cisco_asa); };
```

Answer (score 0):

To collect logs by Linux agent we need send them to the agent over port 25226

```
#syslog config
destination security_oms { udp("127.0.0.1" port(25226)); };
and then create security events configuration file


#oms config
#/etc/opt/microsoft/omsagent/<workspace id>/conf/omsagent.d/
<source>
  type syslog
  port 25226
  bind 127.0.0.1
  protocol_type tcp
  tag oms.security
  format /(?<time>(?:\w+ +){2,3}(?:\d+:){2}\d+|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.[\w\-\:\+]{3,12}):?\s*(?:(?<host>[^: ]+) ?:?)?\s*(?<ident>.*CEF.+?(?=0\|)|%ASA[0-9\-]{8,10})\s*:?(?<message>0\|.*|.*)/
  <parse>
     message_format auto
  </parse>
</source>


<filter oms.security.**>
  type filter_syslog_security
</filter>
```

More about that you could find on oms github page [OMS security events configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/blob/master/docs/Security-Events-Preview-Configuration.md)